# How to set TransactionManager at runtime after the start of the Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to set the query executors (like `JdbcTemplate`, `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, `EntityManager`) and the Transaction Managers (like `DataSourceTransactionManager`, `JpaTransactionManager`) at runtime after the Spring Boot application starts.

The reason I want to do this is that my Spring Boot application doesn't know the database configurations at the start of the application. Once the application starts, the user will send the database configurations in the HTTP request body and based on these configurations the application would need to initialize all these instances. That's why I can't initialize them at the start of the application as spring-managed beans.

Setting the query executors (like `JdbcTemplate`, `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, `EntityManager`) after the application starts is easy, what I am struggling with is setting the Transaction Managers.

For setting `DataSourceTransactionManager`, I am thinking of taking the following approach:

1. Create a `DynamicTransactionManager` class that implements `PlatformTransactionManager` and expose it as a Spring bean.
2. Once the database configuration is available at runtime, initialize the `DataSourceTransactionManager` inside the `DynamicTransactionManager`.

`DynamicTransactionManager`:

```
@Component("DynamicTransactionManager")
public class DynamicTransactionManager implements PlatformTransactionManager {

    private DataSource dataSource;
    private DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager;
    
    // pass the datasource once the db config is available
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager (dataSource);
    }
    
    @Override
    public TransactionStatus getTransaction (TransactionDefinition definition) throws TransactionException { 
        return transactionManager.getTransaction (definition);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void commit (TransactionStatus status) throws TransactionException {
        log.info("Transaction Committed");
        transactionManager.commit(status);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void rollback(TransactionStatus status) throws TransactionException {
        log.info("Rolling back the transaction");
        transactionManager.rollback(status);
    }
}
```

Once the database configuration is available, it calls the `setDataSource` method of this class.
This seems to be working fine for some basic happy path scenarios.

I tried the same for creating a dynamic `JpaTransactionManager`.

`DynamicJpaTransactionManager`:

```
@Component("DynamicJpaTransactionManager")
public class DynamicJpaTransactionManager implements PlatformTransactionManager {

    private JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager;
    
    // pass the entityManagerFactory once the db config is available
    public void setJpaTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){
        jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager (entityManagerFactory);
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public TransactionStatus getTransaction (TransactionDefinition definition) throws TransactionException { 
        return jpaTransactionManager.getTransaction (definition);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void commit (TransactionStatus status) throws TransactionException { 
        log.info("Transaction Committed");
        jpaTransactionManager.commit(status);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void rollback(TransactionStatus status) throws TransactionException {
        log.info("Rolling back the transaction");
        jpaTransactionManager.rollback(status);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work.
When I execute a delete query using `EntityManager` I get `javax.persistence.TransactionManagerRequried` error even when the method is marked with `@Transactional("DynamicJpaTransactionManager")` annotation.

Questions:

1. Is this the correct way to set the Transaction Managers dynamically?
2. Any reason why Spring is not recognizing `DynamicJpaTransactionManager`?

Comment: Don't. You don't need 2 transaction manager, the `JpaTransactionManager` can perfectly handle transactions for the `JdbcTemplate`. If there is just 1 datasource shared between them you only need to use the `JpaTransactionManager`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes the `DataSource` will be the same in all the cases. You are right. Earlier I was not planning to have `EntityManager` so I went with `DataSourceTransactionManager` but now since I have `EntityManager`, I can work with `JpaTransactionManager`. The problem is `DynamicJpaTransactionManager` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Just ditch the dynamic stuff. Instead split your application. At first start only start the endpoint stuff, after receiving the additional configuration start the remainder. That way you don't need to mess around with dynamic stuff. Also are you sure you want to enable config through HTTP, that doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am building a utility whose task is the same irrespective of the DB. We have multiple different SQL DB instances. Currently we are targeting only a few instances but I want the utility to be flexible and should be able to perform the tasks on any database without changing the properties. That's why I am passing the db config in the request body. Is there a problem with the approach I am following? I have never tried splitting the application. Is that a better approach than creating a dynamic transaction manager?

Comment: Do you target them at the same time? Do they need to be extended at runtime? Do they use the same data model or are those different as well ? Or ...

Comment: @M.Deinum No they aren't targetted at the same time. Data models will be different but I am using raw SQL queries for now so I don't have any Entities. And only one db instance will be handled at each run. So no extensions at run time.